# ASP.Net MVC 5 when changing the class data annotations it gives exception error?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I created one Model class Employee

```
public class Employee
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Employee Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Name Is Required") ]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Email { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public int Address { get; set; }

}
```

when I run the application it worked fine after that when I saw that field Address is Int so I 
changed it to String or :

```
public class Employee
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Employee Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Name Is Required") ]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

}
```

when I run the application it gives the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in ProductApps.dll but was not  handled in user code

Additional information: The model backing the 'ProductContext' context has changed since the  database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database    (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
```

Comment: You have to update the databse. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx In package manager console: Update-Database (you have to enable migrations first)

Comment: I am new could you please explain how

Comment: See the link, that I posted. 1) Tools –> Library Package Manager –> Package Manager Console 2) If migrations are not enabled => Run the "Enable-Migrations" command in Package Manager Console 3) "Update-Database -v" in the same console

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're experiencing this exception is because by making a change to the property type within your entity, Entity Framework needs to update the database to reflect your changes.

In this instance it needs to update the `Email` column within the `Employee` table to be of type `int` instead of `string`. And in order to force Entity Framework to do this you need to run the necessary console commands.

To run a console command go to Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console and run the following:

`Add-Migration UpdatedEmailType` followed by `Update-Database`. If you experience an error saying that migrations isn't enabled then you'll need to run the following command to enable the database migriations: `Enable-Migrations`.

**Note:**
Whilst Database Migrations can be a great help in creating a database schema, at times it can be hard work. If you're still experiencing issues then you can always disable migrations and update the database manually within SQL Server Management Studio or Visual Studio's database manager tool.